# Key Binding in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have combo box in my windows form application which contains, string values such as "Tab", "Space", etc. What I need is, when a user selects one of these options in the combo box, it will set it as the key bind to perform some instructions. E.g.

```
string[] KeyBinds = new string[] {"Tab", "Caps Lock", "Shift", "Ctrl", "Alt", "Space", "Enter", "Backspace"};
VelocityKeyBindComboBox.Items.AddRange(KeyBinds);
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space) //I thought of something like e.keycode == Keys.KeyBind
{
    Timer.Stop();
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: *set it as the key bind to perform some instructions*, what do you mean? If you mean set the combobox selected item based on key press I think there a few control properties that should support that.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve], including showing us what you mean by `perform some instructions.`.

Comment: As in the user can select the key bind of their choice from the combo box and then it sets it as that bind. But im not sure how to do it

Comment: unfortunately thats all I have !!!

Comment: Avoid hard-coding key names, they are language sensitive and there are a lot of them.  Use the built-in KeysConverter class, also the best way to ensure what shows in the menu mnemonic matches what the combobox shows.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/19226827/17034

Comment: Maybe you are looking for something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49917834/3110834) to allow users to assign their own custom shortcut key combination for an action.

Answer (score 1):

You can

- directly use an array of Keys instead of strings.`Keys[] KeyBinds = new Keys[] {Keys.Space,Keys.Enter,...};` or rather a List.
- use a `Dictionary<string,Keys>` to map the two, then `if (KeyBinds["Space"] == Keys.Space)` etc etc

Example due to OP request and clarification inside comments:

```
var keyBindings = new Dictionary<string,Keys>();
//assign or reassign all your keys like this:
keyBindings["Close Window"] = Keys.Escape;
keyBindings["Enter"] = Keys.Enter;

//usage:
if (e.KeyCode == keyBindings["Enter"])

//but when you reassign it to:
keyBindings["Enter"] = Keys.F;

//now keyBindings["Enter"] is actually key F
if (e.KeyCode == keyBindings["Enter"])
```

It is also worth looking into [KeysConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keysconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)  which might help. Or you could use ints instead of strings.

Comment: could u please expand on it

Answer (score 1):

I cannot comment, so I will add the answer.

as I understood, you need to get the key of the selected value of the combo box.
If true than do the following:

declare a class that holds your objects:

```
public class MyObj
{
  public string ID;
  public string Name;
}
List<MyObj> mylist = new List<MyObj> ();
// Fill the list with data
// Fill goes here
// Bind the list to the combobox
    combobox1.DatasSource = mylist;
// Set what to show to the user, and which property to be your key
    combobox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    combobox1.ValueMember = "ID"
```

When the user selects a an item you can retrieve it:

```
combobox1.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: The object is unnecessary when Dictionaries are easier

Comment: Ok let me give an example, Lets say you are playing a game, there is an option to change your key bind, lets say for item switch. So lets say if the default key was 1, the user can change it into any key and every time they press the key that they chose it will switch to that item.

Comment: Yes go for dictionaries. you are binding your custom key code (string) to a Keys KeyCode.

Comment: Ok, that is if they switched from the default button A to B, then when pressing  B the event of A should be triggered, right?